# How to deny authentication on port 25 in Exim mail server

Tags: mail-server, smtp, exim

I have the following config in exim.cnf

```
    daemon_smtp_ports = 25:465
    ######################## Exim TLS
    tls_advertise_hosts = *
    tls_on_connect_ports = 465

    tls_certificate=/opt/ssl/certs/server.crt
    tls_privatekey=/opt/ssl/certs/server.key
```

How to deny authentication on 25 port?
Currently authentication is allowed on both ports 25 PLAIN, and 465 SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution is to advertise the AUTH only for those hosts having chosed STARTTLS after unencripted connection to the port 25:

```
auth_advertise_hosts = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
```

After the STARTTLS command is performed and TLS connection is established  the `$tls_cipher` variable for current session becomes non-empty. Client now is advertized that AUTH is allowed while session is secured by TLS and no plaintext passwords are passed over the unuencripted connection.

Sure you can disable AUTH advertizing completely by

```
auth_advertise_hosts =
```

but that is not the best choice.